# Is a Switched Reluctance Motor (SRM) a AC motor or a DC motor?

Tags: motor, ac, dc-motor, stepper-motor, motor-controller

Is the current in a coil of an SRM alternating or not?﻿ I understand that we are giving a DC supply (say battery) but isn't the current reversing its direction. If yes, then it would be called AC but is there a way/design to have unidirectional current (DC) and still be able to operate the motor as an SRM?
Simply put, how would one classify a Switched Reluctance Motor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The terms AC motor and DC motor are not generic terms for all types of motors. They are specific terms associated with particular motor typologies. For example, in brushless permanent magnet motors, the term DC motor refers to a motor that has a trapezoidal back EMF waveform, while the term AC motor refers to one with a sinusoidal waveform. For induction motors the terms make no sense, since all induction motors require a sinusoidal excitation current. For wound motors, the term refers to motors that are self-rectifying, and can run from an alternating supply (although they are more commonly called universal motors).

With regards to switched reluctance machines, the term makes no sense and I have never heard it used. But to answer the rest of your question, yes, the current in the coils of an SRM is unidirectional. This simplifies the drive circuitry and is one of the advantages of the design.

Comment: Thanks. If the current is unidirectional, then I would call it a DC motor. As far as trapezoidal back emf waveform is considered, I would call it an AC motor since if one takes the Fourier transform, there would be zero DC component and multiple non-zero sinusoids of different frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

A Switched Reluctance Motor (SRM) are considered as **DC motors** that emulate the behaviour of an AC motor by switching the DC current between the stator windings. In order to control the switching operation it is necessary to use a controller.

You can find more information in this [link](https://www.maxonmotorusa.com/medias/sys_master/root/8822022406174/Motor-Type-Selection.pdf?attachment=true), where Maxon explains the differences between DC an EC (SRM) motors.

Comment: Do you mean that the current in a particular coil is undergoing reversal?